# How to get absolute url of a Cloudinary Obejct

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary in my django app. But, I get an output like this:

```
{
    "post": "Test",
    "image_field": "image/upload/v1613308988/cizqjtpk59j5orvl2l5e.jpg"
}
```

My MODEL:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="image_field", default=None)
    image_field = CloudinaryField('image')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

My SERIALIZER:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ["post", "image_field"]
```

MY VIEWS:

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ['post', 'image_type']

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly()]
        return [permissions.IsAdminUser()]
```

Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Zayyan Masud - Looks like Cloudinary is returning you the path rather than the entire URL. Do you have a root URL e.g https://cloudinary.app.com or something like that
You can store the root URL in your settings and then when you receive the image_path save it in your image_field. Then when you want to load the image in your templates, you can concatenate them like this

I would write a model method like this

```
  def get_image_url(self):
        return'{}{}'.format(settings.CLOUDINARY_ROOT_URL,self.image_field)
```

Then in your templates, you can simply call

```
- <img src='{{obj.get_image_url}}' />
```